# SQL developer: generate DB doc for other user

Tags: database, oracle, documentation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Admin user in our database. Admin user has access to all database object. I do not have credentials of Admin user.

My application also has Normal  user which has access privileges (select/delete grants etc) on many objects of Admin user. So in SQL developer, when I create connection using Normal user, I can go to "Other Users -> Admin User" and I see many tables/views/triggers/procedures.

When I try to generate DB doc using SQL developer (Right click on connection name -> Generate DB Doc...), generated documentation contains only objects that are created by my Normal user. Report does not contain objects from Admin user, for whom my Normal user has SELECT grants. How can I include objects from Admin user into my generated DB documentation? I only want to include those objects from Admin user for whom my Normal user has SELECT grant.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, This only works for the connected user. That means you'll have to connect to Admin to run the dbdoc for Admin.